# How to import a project with only specific branches from BitBucket to GitHub

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

My BitBucket project (let's call it `Foo`) contains 3 branches (let's call them `master`, `bar` and `foobar`). I would like to import this project to GitHub such that only `master` and `foobar` branches get imported.

The web interface for import on GitHub imports all the branches. But I don't wish `bar` to be imported at all.

A naive way would be to create another project, create the two branches in this new project, and then move the code into these new branches. But by doing this, I will lose the commit history and code evolution meta-data, which is not desirable.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Can't you just delete the third branch after the import?

Comment: Would deleting a branch show up as a commit? Would a developer be ever able to go back in logs and recreate the branch from some old commit's hash?

Comment: No, it's not a commit. Yes, if they know the name and the commit-hash (assuming the commit still exists).

Comment: Then I don't think deleting the third branch will work. I don't want such possibility of recreating the branch.

Comment: @JohnElaine, Check my answer. hope, it will help

Comment: @sunkuet02 Your solution works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the steps:

- First, clone the repository from bitbucket in your system.
- Create a repository in github.
- Change the `remote-url` as like below command:

  ```
  git remote set-url origin github_repo_link.git
  ```
- Then push the `master` branch to github repo running below command:

  ```
  git push origin master
  ```
- Then, push the `foobar` branch:

  ```
  git push origin foobar
  ```

Hope, this will help.